# Mysql - Comparing variable with stored wildcard

Tags: mysql

I have a table in Mysql that houses IP ranges stored as wildcards. For example: 52.% represents every IP that starts with 52. Or for example: 65.154.226.% represents all IP's starting with 65.154.226.

For the original use-case, it worked as expected. However I'm now trying to switch it up, by actually querying on that data stored as wildcard. I want to know if I enter an IP if it exists in the Database (as wildcard). Example query:

`SELECT * FROM IpList WHERE IP LIKE '52.1.1.1';`

Is this possible in one query? If so, could someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks!

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP` along with `substring_index` to achieve this.

Query -

```
select *
from IpList
where IP regexp concat(substring_index("52.1.1.1", ".", 1), ".%.%.%")
   or IP regexp concat(substring_index("52.1.1.1", ".", 2), ".%.%")
   or IP regexp concat(substring_index("52.1.1.1", ".", 3), ".%")
   or IP regexp "52.1.1.1";
```

It will give you the list of records in `IpList` table.